# Single click on button not working but double click does the work in C# revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api

While I'm Click Button from my FORM, Single click on button not working but the double click does the work.

Please help me, How to resolve and let me know why for my knowledge.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE8gv.png)

Designer Code is

```
            // searchButton
            // 
            this.searchButton.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            this.searchButton.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.searchButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 144);
            this.searchButton.Name = "searchButton";
            this.searchButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97, 31);
            this.searchButton.TabIndex = 0;
            this.searchButton.Text = "Search";
            this.searchButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.searchButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.searchButton_Click);
            //
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some of us can't see the image. Would you please edit to embed it?

Answer (score 0):

Use *MouseClick* event instead of *Click* event

```
this.searchButton.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.searchButton_Click);
```

Comment: Thanks, Hokage but still not working I have to do anything else

Comment: Oops okay, also did you put `object sender, EventArgs e` in the searchButton_Click function as parameters?

Comment: yes,  private void searchButton_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: I check the button Properties and MouseEnter is empty then I fill it with button_Click. it's Working now.   Thanks, Hokage